# Spring Controller method executed twice

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have integrated Spring Security with Spring MVC and seeing strange behaviour. Every method in the Controller is executed twice for the same request. I googled for it quite a bit but didn't help much. The closest I could find is this http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-83158.html I tried the suggestions without any success.

Here is my web.xml :

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>     
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
 <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>
         /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-app-context.xml            
         /WEB-INF/application-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Here is relevant part of applicationcontext.xml :

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.*" />
  <context:spring-configured/>

 <mvc:annotation-driven />

 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/conf/myConfig.properties"   />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

The servlet-context.xml only has mapping for the InternalResourceViewResolver

The security-context.xml is as follows :

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>

    <http auto-config="false" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" >
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="ROLE_USER"/>

    <custom-filter before="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" ref="cookieSecurityContextFilter" />
    <custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="logoutfilter" />          
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationFilter" />
    <custom-filter after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" ref="customExceptionFilter" />
    </http>


    <beans:bean id="logoutfilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
     <beans:constructor-arg value="/"/>
     <beans:constructor-arg ref="customLogouthandler"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

And then further mapping for the filters. 
Am I doing something wrong in the configuration that could lead to the controller being called twice. I have checked the logs and the beans are instantiated only once. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the server logs please. Also spring security interceptor-urls are applied in the order they are declared. Move the global intercepter /** in end (not that it will help with controller called twice issue)

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone stumbles on this post and solution posted here thinking it will fix the duplicate requests, please first check if it is your browser/rest client making the additional call.

I wasted many hours trying to configure app and servlet contexts "after seeing the first suggested solution", until I figured it was the rest client on certain browsers (Chrome) creating an additional request for "GET requests on image resources". Curl showed only one method execution.

However, I do agree that it is a good practice to separate controller specific beans and their required Spring beans into servlet-context and keep all common beans in app-context. This is especially important if you have multiple Spring dispatcher servlet- in your web.xml.

Elaborating the previous answer:

You can either define both component-scan and mvc in the same context file to keep it simple.

app-context.xml:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="..." />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 ...
```

Or separate them as follows:

app-context.xml:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="....">
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
<context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" type="annotation"/>
<context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
...
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="...">
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" type="annotation"/>
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try moving `<mvc:..` elements to servlet-context.xml, maybe having it on applicationContext.xml causes you to have duplicate dispatcher servlet (although beans are only created once)

Scan all components except `@Controller` on applicationContext.xml by using `<context:exclude-filter..`. Likewise scan only `@Controller` on servlet-context.xml using `<context:include-filter..`

Comment: I added following to applicationcontext.xml <context:component-scan base-package="com.*" >
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
 and following to servlet-context.xml : <context:component-scan base-package="com.*" >
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>. Also tried moving <mvc:.. to servlet-context.xml. But now it does not find the controller, get this error : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/some.org/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'